# Codeigniter email issue, I'm struggling to send email one after another

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am tring to send mails through codeigniter email class. Following is a method from my controller :

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('xxx@yyy.zzz');

for($i=0; $i< count($data); $i++)
    {

        $this->email->to($data[$i]['email']);       
        $this->email->subject('Notification');
        $this->email->message('EMAIL');
        $this->email->send();
    }

$admin_data = $this->admin_model->get_admin_detail();

$this->email->to($admin_data[0]['email']);
$this->email->subject('Notification');
$this->email->message('EMAIL');
$this->email->send();
```

I am getting mails using my script in `for loop`. But then it shows `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`. And I did not get mail to my admin email.

Expected : emails to users using `for loop` [it's working]
and one email [after for loop ends] to admin mail.

Thanks.!

Comment: 500 error means some thing wrong in your code, enable error reporting and see what actual error is it printing

Comment: try `$this->email->clear()` after the `$this->email->send()` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);

    for($i=0; $i< count($data); $i++)
    {
        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->from('xxx@yyy.zzz');
        $this->email->to($data[$i]['email']);       
        $this->email->subject('Notification');
        $this->email->message('EMAIL');
        $this->email->send();
    }

    $admin_data = $this->admin_model->get_admin_detail();

    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->from('xxx@yyy.zzz');
    $this->email->to($admin_data[0]['email']);
    $this->email->subject('Notification');
    $this->email->message('EMAIL');
    $this->email->send();
```